# Globally start a helper function

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I want to test for the console errors in my application?

I know how to get them using

`browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLog) {})`
in afterEach()

What i want to achieve is that i want to use it globally. As in, I don't want to call the helper function in every spec. I want to run it by default when I start the config file and detect if any errors appear in the console.

Comment: Can't you do this using `onComplete()` in protractor config? https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#LC405

Comment: @TehBeardedOne Heh you beat me to it, I was writing up my answer.  onComplete works for me.  You should just add that as the answer yourself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @TehBeardedOne suggested in the comments above, you can do this using the `onComplete()` function of your config file.

```
onComplete: function () {
    browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLog) {
        console.log(browserLog);
    });
}
```

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be *reinventing the wheel* - there is already a plugin that would check the browser console errors for you:

- [protractor-console-plugin](https://github.com/angular/protractor-console-plugin)

Comment: I followed the instructions in this page : https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-console.
But when I run my config file, it says that Error: Cannot find module 'protractor-console' , but when I checked inside the node_modules folder, I can find this plugin. What to do for it